# How to close the bottom sheet when you click anywhere in the window

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the code for bottom sheet so that the panel closes if I click anywhere in the window except the panel itself, I tried to wrap everything in GestureDetector and do it when I press a button, but it doesn’t work

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget bottomSheet() {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 137,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: Offset(0, 3),
              ),
            ],
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                (AppLocalizations.of(context)!.chooseprofilephoto),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.camera,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Text(
                          (AppLocalizations.of(context)!.camera),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      takePhoto(ImageSource.camera);
                    },
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.image,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Text(
                          (AppLocalizations.of(context)!.gallery),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      takePhoto(ImageSource.gallery);
                    },
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.remove_circle,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Text(
                          (AppLocalizations.of(context)!.removephoto),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      removePhotoFromProfile();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

In the second part of the code, I use the bottom sheet and it opens, but does not close if I click anywhere in the window.

```
child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        onPressed: () {
             showBottomSheet(
                 context: context,
                 builder: (builder) =>
                    bottomSheet(),
                    );
              },
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
showBottomSheet(
             context: context,
             builder: (builder) =>
                bottomSheet(),
                );
```

to

```
 showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        isDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => bottomSheet()
    );
```

And you don't need `GestureDetector`.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `showModalBottomSheet()` instead

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => bottomSheet(),
);
```